# kendo combobox delete value that is not in datasource after choosing value from datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a problem with the kendoUI combo box control – 
The combo allows to type text which is not in the datasource.
But, if I put in text that is not in the list after choosing a item that is in the list – the value is deleted.

Can anyone help me out with the issue?

Comment: Do you want to disable text input or keep it? You are using Razor syntax?

Comment: not to disable, I want to keep it. I use Razor synaxt, but it happens also by javascript syntax.